# Get first 5 values from array

Tags: jquery

From my ata i only have to fetch first 5 values. Using Jquery how it is possible.

```
    var server =[
    {
        "jobid": "4",
        "browser": "FF20",
        "subemail": "0poo",
        "userid": "60",
        "names": "abc@gmail.com",
        "datetime": "Thu Oct 03 2013 13:41:06 GMT+0530 (IST)",
        "_id": "524d269a6d32804512000001"
    },
    {
        "jobid": "34",
        "browser": "GC23",
        "subemail": "0poo",
        "userid": "60",
        "names": "abc@gmail.com",
        "datetime": "Thu Oct 03 2013 13:41:47 GMT+0530 (IST)",
        "_id": "524d26c36d32804512000002"
    },
    {
        "jobid": "34",
        "browser": "IE8",
        "subemail": "0poo",
        "userid": "60",
        "names": "abc@gmail.com",
        "datetime": "Thu Oct 03 2013 13:41:50 GMT+0530 (IST)",
        "_id": "524d26c66d32804512000003"
    },
    {
        "jobid": "34",
        "browser": "FF20",
        "subemail": "0poo",
        "userid": "60",
        "names": "abc@gmail.com",
        "datetime": "Thu Oct 03 2013 13:41:53 GMT+0530 (IST)",
        "_id": "524d26c96d32804512000004"
    },
    {
        "jobid": "34",
        "browser": "GC23",
        "subemail": "0poo",
        "userid": "60",
        "names": "abc@gmail.com",
        "datetime": "Thu Oct 03 2013 13:41:55 GMT+0530 (IST)",
        "_id": "524d26cb6d32804512000005"
    },
    {
        "jobid": "34",
        "browser": "IE8",
        "subemail": "0poo",
        "userid": "60",
        "names": "abc@gmail.com",
        "datetime": "Thu Oct 03 2013 13:41:57 GMT+0530 (IST)",
        "_id": "524d26cd6d32804512000006"
    },
    {
        "jobid": "86",
        "browser": "FF20",
        "subemail": "",
        "userid": "0",
        "names": "Guest",
        "datetime": "Thu Oct 03 2013 13:42:27 GMT+0530 (IST)",
        "_id": "524d26eb6d32804512000007"
    },
    {
        "jobid": "86",
        "browser": "GC23",
        "subemail": "",
        "userid": "0",
        "names": "Guest",
        "datetime": "Thu Oct 03 2013 13:42:31 GMT+0530 (IST)",
        "_id": "524d26ef6d32804512000008"
    },
    {
        "jobid": "86",
        "browser": "IE8",
        "subemail": "",
        "userid": "0",
        "names": "Guest",
        "datetime": "Thu Oct 03 2013 13:42:32 GMT+0530 (IST)",
        "_id": "524d26f06d32804512000009"
    },
    {
        "jobid": "86",
        "browser": "FF20",
        "subemail": "",
        "userid": "60",
        "names": "abc@gmail.com",
        "datetime": "Thu Oct 03 2013 13:43:01 GMT+0530 (IST)",
        "_id": "524d270d6d3280451200000a"
    },
    {
        "jobid": "86",
        "browser": "GC23",
        "subemail": "",
        "userid": "60",
        "names": "abc@gmail.com",
        "datetime": "Thu Oct 03 2013 13:43:03 GMT+0530 (IST)",
        "_id": "524d270f6d3280451200000b"
    },
    {
        "jobid": "86",
        "browser": "IE8",
        "subemail": "",
        "userid": "60",
        "names": "abc@gmail.com",
        "datetime": "Thu Oct 03 2013 13:43:05 GMT+0530 (IST)",
        "_id": "524d27116d3280451200000c"
    },
    {
        "jobid": "86",
        "browser": "FF20",
        "subemail": "",
        "userid": "11",
        "names": "priya@gmail.com",
        "datetime": "Thu Oct 03 2013 13:44:35 GMT+0530 (IST)",
        "_id": "524d276b6d3280451200000d"
    },
    {
        "jobid": "86",
        "browser": "GC23",
        "subemail": "",
        "userid": "11",
        "names": "priya@gmail.com",
        "datetime": "Thu Oct 03 2013 13:44:37 GMT+0530 (IST)",
        "_id": "524d276d6d3280451200000e"
    },
    {
        "jobid": "86",
        "browser": "IE8",
        "subemail": "",
        "userid": "11",
        "names": "priya@gmail.com",
        "datetime": "Thu Oct 03 2013 13:44:39 GMT+0530 (IST)",
        "_id": "524d276f6d3280451200000f"
    },
    {
        "jobid": "86",
        "browser": "FF20",
        "subemail": "",
        "userid": "11",
        "names": "priya@gmail.com",
        "datetime": "Thu Oct 03 2013 13:45:13 GMT+0530 (IST)",
        "_id": "524d27916d32804512000010"
    }
]
```

-

```
serverResult.forEach(function (result) {
// How can i get the first 5 values from the data

});
```

Comment: I've edited out all references to JSON. There's no JSON in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the slice method

```
var first5 = server.slice(0,5)
```

---

```
array.slice(begin[, end])
```

Get the detailed Syntax [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 3):

Try using this:

```
server.slice(0,5)
```

Comment: From (SLICE)[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice] : Zero-based index at which to end extraction. slice extracts up to but not including end. "

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   var obj = server[i];

   // Do something...
   // obj.jobid, obj.browser, etc.
}
```

Of if you're using jQuery:

```
$.getJSON('/api/Controller/Action', {}, function (result) {
    $.each(result, function (i, v) {
        if (i > 4) return false; // Stop processing after 5 entries

        // 'v' now is your current object
        // v.jobid, v.browser, etc.
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be **[.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)** and not .forEach()

```
server.each(function (index,result) {
  if(index<5){
   //do stuff;
  //array.push(item);
  }     
});
```

Comment: showing SyntaxError: unlabeled break must be inside loop or switch

Comment: @Psl used `return false`; check it

Answer (score 0):

```
for(j=0;j<server.length;j++){
    var elms = server[j];
    for(i=0;i<elms.length;i++){
         if(i<4){
             console.log(elms[i].jobid); //etc
          }else{
       break;
      }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, i guess that this is what you need,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.each(server, function(index, item) {
                if(index < 5) {
                    //DoSomeThings
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            });
       });
```